# O que significa "[:, : -1]" a seguir ao iloc no Python?

Tags: python

Tenho a seguinte linha de código:

```
X = data.iloc[:, :-1].values
```

Não consigo perceber porque tem `:` antes do `-1`.

Comment: Significa que está lendo de trás pra frente a lista, no geral eu acho que o código tá fazendo é invertendo as posições, o que era X1 é atribuido com YN e XN, com Y1

Comment: só dando mais detalhes o ":" significa de vai pegar de "index x até index y", exemplo 1:3, pegar do index 1 ao 3, no seu caso ele vai pegar até a penultima coluna

Answer (score 0):

Quando você deixa em branco os dois pontos, significa que você quer que retorne todos os índices.

O primeiro ":" significa que ele vai ler da primeira à última linha (índice).

A "," significa que o próximo ":" trata das colunas.

O ":-1" significa que ele retorna da primeira coluna até a coluna "-1", que corresponde à última coluna.

Assim, ele retorna todas as linhas e colunas do dataframe.